# Access React component's function in HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance

I'm building a higher order component for my various React components. In this HOC, I need to access the child's methods and call them. How can I do it?

example HOC:

```
export default function withHOC(Component) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      if (Component.someFunction) {
          Component.someFunction()
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

example component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  someFunction() {
    console.log("something done here, for example setState")
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div></div>
    ); 
  }
}

// then it's used like this
export default withHOC(App)
```

I know that in some case it might not even make sense to solve it like this, but for example framework Next.js can do something similar with it's getInitialProps function.

Comment: Will all components that are connected to HOC have someFunction, if not, if probably a bad idea to do this in HOC

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri most of them will, yes

Comment: What if the wrapped component doesn't have that function, what would you want to do then

Comment: It doesn't matter for now. If it happens, there will be some function that will check it.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to call the child components method in componentDidMount of HOC, a better alternative is to indeed call the method in the `componentDidMount` of the component itself, which would take care of the case when the child component doesn't have a function or if it is composed of multiple HOCs like

```
export default function withHOC(Component) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     this.someFunction();
  }
  someFunction() {
    console.log("something done here, for example setState")
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div></div>
    ); 
  }
}
```

However if you still want to call the function in child component, you would make use of refs(however if the App component is composed of other HOCs, this won't work)

```
export default function withHOC(Component) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
         this.cmp.someFunction();
    }
    render() {
      return <Component ref={(ref) => this.cmp = ref} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  someFunction() {
    console.log("something done here, for example setState")
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div></div>
    ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: One note that `ref` is missing as a parameter. Should be `return <Component ref={(ref) => this.cmp = ref} {...this.props} />;`

Answer (score 2):

If you replace :

```
if (Component.someFunction) {
  Component.someFunction()
}
```

By :

```
if (this.someFunction) {
  this.someFunction();
}
```

You should be able to access you component instance function.

Also, next.js getInitialProps function is static, that's why you can access it directly from the component class.

Comment: Thank you, I have already version with static methods, it works well, but that's not what I'm asking for.

Comment: The only problem is that I need to be able to access this in that method, that's why static isn't a good solution.

Comment: But I give you a point for reminding me of that the getInitialProps is static, and for finding out that this.someFunction works.